# Unable to install tightvncserver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: perl, tightvncserver

Hi is there anyone encounter this error before? I have tried many ways removing and reinstall etc, but it still just don't work. Is it because there is another version of PERL exist on the server? Please advise.

Screenshot of error - unable to install tightvncserver due to perl dependency
[image]

```
perl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5
  Version table:
     5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 500
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.22.1-9 500
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.18.2-2ubuntu1.6 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
tightvncserver:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.3.10-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.3.10-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Try X11-realvnc server. Works great on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @PranalNarayan am I still able to use VNC client to do the remoting?

Comment: @LukeLee Do you have enabled *universe*, *main* for *xenial*, *xenial-updates* and *xenial-security* repositories? Did you forget to run `apt-get update` before `apt-get install tightvncserver`? On my 16.04 it installs normally.

Comment: @N0rbert Yes I did, I suspect is another newer version of PERL being install using another method.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy perl tightvncserver` to the question (text output is preferred).

Comment: Version numbers are normal, but *trusty-security* should be disabled in `sources.list`. Try to install perl version with `sudo apt-get install perl=5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5`

Comment: @N0rbert still not working. How can I remove and purge all the Perls on my machine? Any idea? I think that is causing some of the problems.

Comment: You can't `perl` as it is core system component. Check your sources.list again for errors, switch to `archive.ubuntu.com` in all lines.  Then try to fix your problems with `aptitude` and ensure that `sudo apt-get update` do not produce errors.

Comment: @N0rbert, is there away to download and install all the related packages or dependent files?